# Get image dimensions with php

Tags: php, html, image

I'm trying to echo the width and height of an image into a looping array I have.  Everything other than the width and height seems to be there.   The images are displayed in a carousel that I have.  For the carousel to work properly it likes to have the image width and height.  I don't want to enter manual values and distort the images!!

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
 <?php do {
 $image = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$row_rs_imgpath['userimagespath'].$row_rs_smimg['thumbfile'];
 $x= imagesx($image);
 $y = imagesy($image);

 ?>


    <img src="<?php echo $row_rs_imgpath['userimagespath'].$row_rs_smimg['thumbfile']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row_rs_smimg['imgname']; ?>" width="<?php echo $x;?>" height="<?php echo $y;?>" />


 <?php } while ($row_rs_smimg = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_smimg)); ?>
```

And when you view the page source code you get the following:

```
<img src="/images/uploads/my-future-car-1358783315_thumb.jpg"width="" height="" />
<img src="/images/uploads/albert_docks_liverpool-1358872736_thumb.jpg" width="" height="" />
```

I have also tried

```
list($width, $height)= getimagesize($image);
```

but that doesn't work either. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: You forgot to put a few code blocks in. Using the filename for the alt is extremely annoying for those that need it

Comment: @RyanB the alt is the name of the image not the file name but yes I did forget to output it

Comment: It's totally okay to post your own answer, and then accept it as the solution! That way future searchers will learn from what you did.

Comment: @NateCook brill ill do that in future thanks nate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the full path to your file, when using *getimagesize()*? It doesn't work when it couldn't find the image.

Comment: thank you I had not referenced the full path like I though I had.  You have solved my problem I have been on for hour thank you very much.  I have updated my question to the solved version.  I needed the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] function.

Answer (score 1):

Your current `$image` is a string. The functions you are trying to use are meant to be used on a resources from the GD library.

The easier way to do things, if you just need the dimensions, is to not use the GD library at all (it's overkill for what you're doing). I would recommend using `getimagesize`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

```
$size = getimagesize($filename);
echo $size[0]; //width
echo $size[1]; //height
```

Answer (score 0):

`imagesx` and `imagesy` work on image resources, not file names. That line of code with `getimagesize` is the right one, but the way you're addressing images will only work in a browser, not in the file system.

`/images/image.gif` will work in the browser, but you need either a relative path (`../../images/image.gif`) or a file-system specific path (`/users/joe/www/images/image.gif`) for the `getimagesize` function to find the right file.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I have solved the issue and updated my code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

#### Get image size from Image object:

```
$source = imagecreatefrompng(...);
$width = imagesx($source);
$height = imagesy($source);
```

For `imagesx` and `imagesy` function, you need to pass a resource, not string like you are doing.

#### Get image size from path:

```
$size= getimagesize('sample-image.jpg');
$width = $gis[1];
$height = $gis[1];
```

Or

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename)
```